# pass arguments to zip() as a string, avoiding using exec()

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have several lists, for example A,B,C,D,E which I want to combine using zip() in various ways depending on user input, for example.

```
output_list = zip(A,C,D)
output_list = zip(A,D,E,B)
output_list = zip(C,D)
```

I need to pass the arguments as a string which I believe can probably do using getattr(), for example, something like:

```
my_arguments = 'A,C,D' #string
output_list = getattr(zip, my_arguments)
```

I'm getting the error

```
'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'raw,dd,utm'
```

Am I barking up the right tree? (I don't want to use exec())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like `zip(*[locals()[x] for x in my_arguments.split(',')])` would probably work.

possibly replacing `locals` with `globals` if the variables are defined in the global namespace.

If you know that you're only gong to be dealing with `A`, `B`, `C` ..., you can pack them into a dict ahead of time:

```
namespace = {'A':A,
             'B':B,
             'C':C,
            }
zip_args = [namespace[x.strip()] for x in my_arguments.split(',')]
output = zip(*zip_args)
```

This is really just a more explicit version of what I was saying you could do above (which used the `locals()` dictionary as the namespace mapping).  Since this is the most explicit version, it is the one that I would use ... Then you don't have to worry about the user somehow including something in `output` that they shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
def zipper(args):
    A = [1, 2]
    B = [3, 4]
    C = [5, 6]

    lists = locals()
    return zip(*map(lambda var: lists[var], args.split(',')))


print zipper('A,B')
print zipper('B,C')
```

But you probably should not have these lists as separate variables. A dictionary is probably cleaner:

```
lists = {
   'A': [...],
   'B': [...]
}
```

You would still use

```
zip(*map(lambda var: lists[var], my_arguments.split(',')))
```

or

```
zip(*[lists[var] for var in my_arguments.split(',')])
```

though.

Comment: This also works. I like it, sorry I could not also tick this answer.